# How to stop memory leak in useEffect react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io, chat, use-effect

Hello I am facing a memory leak in my useEffect and I am getting this error "Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function."

I am trying to update my messages state when I emit the message from the backend.

my code looks like this

```
    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on("message", data => {
            setMessages(prevVal => [...prevVal, {
                author: data.id,
                text: data.text
            }]);
        });
    }, [socket]);
```

Please help and Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens if your component has already unmounted by the time the set state call is made, and this can happen because you're calling an asynchronous function `socket.on` which uses a callback.

Whenever you have these asynchronous side effects that may try to alter the state of your component, you should use [a cleanup pattern](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup).

So for example (given a socket.io socket)

```
useEffect(() => {
  const onMessage = data => {
      setMessages(prevVal => [...prevVal, {
        author: data.id,
        text: data.text
      }]);
    };

  // Register listener
  socket.on("message", onMessage);

  // On cleanup, remove the attached listener
  return () => socket.off("message", onMessage)

}, [socket]);
```

The `cleanup` function returned by `useEffect` will run when the component is unmounted, causing the set state call to be skipped.